# LDAP authentication failed:data 52e

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-boot, spring-security, ldap

I am trying to authenticate through LDAP account:

```
@Configuration
    protected static class AnnotationConfiguration extends GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter{

        @Override
        public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception{
            authenticationManagerBuilder
                .ldapAuthentication()
                .userSearchFilter("(cn={0})")
                .userSearchBase("ou=User Accounts,dc=ph,dc=sunlife")
                //.groupSearchFilter("")
                //.userDnPatterns("cn={0},ou=Functional Accounts")
                //.rolePrefix("")
                .contextSource()
                .url("ldap://ldapvs.ph.sun/dc=ph,dc=sun")
                .managerPassword("sun_01").managerDn("cn=JPH,ou=Non Internet user,ou=Staff,ou=User Accounts");

        }

    }
```

After entering the username and password to the login page, i am getting:

```
14:01:32 [http-bio-8085-exec-7] UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter - An internal error occurred while trying to authenticate the user.
org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A8, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v1db1
```

Though i know my password and username are valid.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in wiki http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=LDAP_Error_Codes#gsc.tab=0

> Indicates an Active Directory (AD) AcceptSecurityContext error, which
>   is returned when the username is valid but the combination of password
>   and user credential is invalid. This is the AD equivalent of LDAP
>   error code 49.